# How do you get Google product rich snippets working on WooCommerce

Tags: google, wordpress, ecommerce, rich-snippets

I have just set up a WooCommerce site and I am trying to get the reviews on it to show up in the Google rich snippets. How can i do this? Is there any out-the-box plugins to make it work?

Currently it pulls in some data in the Rich Snippets Structured Data Testing Tool but it does not show the 'Star rating' and 'Price' in the search results?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you looking for plugin recommendations or code troubleshooting advice? If the latter, please include your code in your question.

Comment: how are you getting on with this? I'm working on the same thing on my test site (it in maintenance or id link to it). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

It can take some time for the data to start showing in SERPs. Assuming the Rich Snippet testing tool is reporting that your markup is OK, I would just wait for a month or so. In my experience, that's approximately how long it took for the extra meta data to start showing on Google's SERPs, and even then it's spotty at best even on the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

GWT's Rich Snippet Data testing tool is quite awesome. When you test an URL, it shows you how the rich snippet on the SERP may look like. However as many answers already submitted say, that it takes some time for this to actually start reflecting in the SERP.

I don't think that's your problem though. If you are not able to see the review snippet in the tool preview itself, then most likely there is some problem that you are facing. GWT also tells you what kind of schemas it found on that page, and whether that schema is incomplete or not.

I have not worked with WooCommerce so I do not know the granularities of the way it uses schemas, but if you compare your mark-up with the syntax provided in [schema.org/Review](http://schema.org/Review) and the one in [schema.org/Product](http://schema.org/Product) then it might help.

Answer (score 0):

When I run a WooCommerce demo site in the rich snippet testing tool I see the price. Since none have reviews I can't speak for those but if you check the source code you'll see if they have the hReview schema.

Keep in mind even if your website is compliant and has the correct markup Google may not display it in search results so waiting a month or more may not be a solution.

Comment: even if it does not show in the SERP's it should still show up in the GWT's Rich Snippet Data Testing tool. His question is why is it not even testing there.

Comment: @Prasad as I suggested they should view the source of WC. And in `review.php` it has `<li itemprop="reviews" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">` so WC does include hReview.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: The plugin WordPress SEO from Yoast does this almost automatically!